# Why spring boot does not find GroovySystem?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, groovy

I am using springboot project with batch within intellij.
when I start to debug the project, gets the following error.

**Which part am I missing and how to fix it?

What is the compatible groovy version for spring-bean?**

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: groovy/lang/GroovySystem
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.<init>(GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.<init>(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:84) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createBeanDefinitionLoader(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:706) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at be.kava.informix.batch.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:70) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: groovy.lang.GroovySystem
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I checked the `GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java` i see this import in red: `import groovy.lang.GroovySystem;`

I have added this dependency but I get another error as below.

```
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
    <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.5</version>
</dependency>
```

error:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Implementing class
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:468) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_191]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.groovy.GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.<init>(GroovyBeanDefinitionReader.java:150) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.BeanDefinitionLoader.<init>(BeanDefinitionLoader.java:84) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createBeanDefinitionLoader(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.load(SpringApplication.java:706) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareContext(SpringApplication.java:392) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
at be.kava.informix.batch.BatchApplication.main(BatchApplication.java:70) [classes/:na]
```

I have added this plugin also to my pom.

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
            <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>addSources</goal>
                        <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        <goal>generateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testGenerateStubs</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        <goal>removeStubs</goal>
                        <goal>removeTestStubs</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed the issue by removing all the versions from dependency and relied on Spring starter.
Adding version to dependency will cause the version conflict. Spring starter knows what is the suitable version.